# Discord.JS Prune Command Also Prunes User Pins

Tags: module, discord.js, fs

I have a prune command for my Discord moderation bot that I am building and it does pretty much what I need. But it also goes a tad too far. It is also pruning user pins which i a bit too much for a simple prune command.

I would like to know what edit I need to make so it can't prune user pins.

Here is my code:

```
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'prune',
    description: 'Prune up to 99 messages.',
    aliases: '[p]',
    execute(message, args) {
        if(message.member.roles.find("name", "Helper")){
            const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1;
            if (isNaN(amount)) {
                return message.reply('that doesn\'t seem to be a valid number.');

                } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
                    return message.reply('you need to input a number between 1 and 99.');
                }

            message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
                    console.error(err);
                    message.channel.send('there was an error trying to prune messages in this channel!');
            });

        }else{
            message.channel.send(`Access Denied`);
        }
}};
```

Naturally it's suppose to prune messages. Which it does. However, it's not suppose to rune user pins.

As it is it also prunes user pins.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can bot clear script skip the pinned messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61136348/how-can-bot-clear-script-skip-the-pinned-messages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing an amount of messages to bulk delete, you can use a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) of messages.

To fetch the messages in a channel, use [`TextChannel.fetchMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=fetchMessages). Then, you can retrieve a new Collection *excluding* pinned messages by using the [`Collection.filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) method. In the predicate function, you should check the message's [`pinned`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=pinned) property.

Consider this example...

```js
message.channel.fetchMessages({ limit: amount })
  .then(fetchedMessages => {
    const messagesToPrune = fetchedMessages.filter(msg => !msg.pinned);
    return message.channel.bulkDelete(messagesToPrune, true);
  })
  .then(prunedMessages => {
    message.channel.send(`Deleted ${prunedMessages.size} message${prunedMessages.size !== 1 ? 's' : ''}.`);
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: This is causing an error to show up in console and it's not actually doing anything

Here is the error


```
(node:6154) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
ReferenceError: messagesToPrune is not defined
    at message.channel.fetchMessages.then.fetchedMessages (/home/ubuntu/PhantomGuard/commands/prune.js:21:39)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: @JoshuaVL1988 My code had a typo in declaring the variable, my apologies. I've edited the answer to fix it.

Comment: Thank you. This appears to be doing what I was needing. However is the message it responds with suppose to be "Deleted [object Map] messages."? or is it suppose to be more specific?

Comment: @JoshuaVL1988 I've edited the answer again to fix that. It'll now display the *number* of deleted messages rather than try to display the whole *Collection*.